# How to subtract value from same month last year in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have the below dataframe and I need to subtract value from same month last year and save it in output:

```
date            value     output
01-01-2012      20        null
01-02-2012      10
01-03-2012      40
01-06-2012      30
01-01-2013      20           0
01-02-2013      30          20
01-02-2014      60          30
01-03-2014      50          null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create `DatetimeIndex`, then subtract by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) with new `Series` by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) by `12` months, `MS` is for [start of month](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)
df = df.set_index('date')

df['new'] = df['value'].sub(df['value'].shift(freq='12MS'))
print (df)
            value  output   new
date                           
2012-01-01     20     NaN   NaN
2012-02-01     10     NaN   NaN
2012-03-01     40     NaN   NaN
2012-06-01     30     NaN   NaN
2013-01-01     20     0.0   0.0
2013-02-01     30    20.0  20.0
2014-02-01     60    30.0  30.0
2014-03-01     50     NaN   NaN
```